# bash: Why is the value of ${@:-1} different to ${@: -1}?

Tags: arrays, bash

Why does the addition of the space between the `:` and the `-1` change the behaviour shown below?

```
(ins)$ set a b c d
(ins)$ echo ${@:-1}
a b c d
(ins)$ echo ${@: -1}
d
(ins)$
```

The same behaviour also affects `$*`.

I'm running `GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: At some point, you'll have to read the friendly [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) about parameter expansions. `${parameter:-word}` v.s. `${parameter:offset}` with a negative offset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity with the parameter expansion pattern:

```
${parameter:-word}
```

which means to substitute the expansion of `word` if `parameter is unset or null; otherwise the expansion of parameter is substituted.

So for the slicing operation, a space or parentheses is used:

```
$ set a b c d

$ echo "${@: -1}"
d

$ echo "${@:(-1)}"
d
```

Comment: Didn't know that parentheses were possible. Thanks!